# How do I set a default value based on an associated model in Rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, database-migration, default-value

I have a model called `userWorkshop` it references both a `User` and a `Workshop`.

`Workshops` have a *price* column.

`userWorkshops` have an *override_price* column.

I would like its default value of the *override_price* column of the `UserWorkShop`  to be based on the *price* column of the `Workshop` it is associated with.

I want to set this value in my ActiveRecord migration. I imagine it might look something like this:

```
  def change
    add_column :userWorkshops, :override_price, :float, default: "self.workshop.price" 
  end
```

Any idea on the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a way to do all of this in one migration. I would take advantage of the before_initialize callback.

```rb
class UserWorkshop < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users
  belongs_to :workshop

  before_initialize :initial_values, unless: persisted?

  def initial_values
    self.override_price = workshop.price
  end
end
```

The benefit of this is that you can easily change your override_price to be something like this `self.override_price = workshop.price/2` to give them a 50% discount or anything else of that sort.

And then in a migration, something to take care of the old data.

```rb
def change
  UserWorkshop.find_each do |uw|
    uw.override_price = uw.workshop.price
    uw.save
  end
end
```

Comment: `UserWorkshop.find_each` is better, to avoid loading all records into memory at once.

Comment: The suggestion of find_each has been implemented. Thanks, @CassandraS.